# Injecting parameter in Typhoon Swift

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

I am using the following code to inject a enum parameter in Typhoon in Swift:

```
public dynamic func introPageViewController() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(UIPageViewController.self)  {
        (definition) in
            definition.useInitializer("initWithTransitionStyle:navigationOrientation:options:"){

        (initializer) in
        initializer.injectParameterWith(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll)
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that injectParameterWith  method only accepts parameters of type AnyObject and the parameter I want to inject is of Int type so this code gives a compiler error. 
How would I achieve this without causing any compiler error or crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in the Typhoon User Guide [here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#using-auto-boxing--nsvalue-to-inject-primitives), to inject an enum it is necessary to box it as an NSNumber.  I'm actually not sure how to box explicitly in Swift but you could do it with something like:

```
var num: NSNumber = mode.rawValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to try it now but according to [this](http://www.drewag.me/posts/swift-s-weird-handling-of-basic-value-types-and-anyobject) you should be able to just add `import Foundation` to the top of the file and it will do an implicit cast to `NSNumber` from `Int`

Comment: I am not able to do so. it keeps saying UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle is not convertible to NSNumber